# checkout_cart_product_add_after observer not firing in live server but working in local server

Tags: magento

I’m having some trouble in my module, it is working fine in local server but it’s not working in dev server.
Here is my code:
app/etc/modules/Ecophone_Specialoffer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
         <Ecophone_Specialoffer>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Ecophone_Specialoffer>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Config file
app/code/local/Ecophone/Specialoffer/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
      <Ecophone_Specialoffer>
          <version>0.1.0</version>
      </Ecophone_Specialoffer>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
     <events>
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
               <Ecophone_Specialoffer_Model_Observer>
                  <type>singleton</type>
                  <class>Ecophone_Specialoffer_Model_Observer</class>
                  <method>changingPrice</method>
               </Ecophone_Specialoffer_Model_Observer>
           </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Observer.php
app/code/local/Ecophone/Specialoffer/Model/Observer.php

```
class Ecophone_Specialoffer_Model_Observer {
    public function changingPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $obs){
             die('hello');
        }
}
```

I don't know what is gonna wrong in dev server.

Comment: did not get any error it adds product as usual, but it show `hello` in local server if we add products in cart

Answer (score 2):

Check for difference between capital letters and downcase becouse Windows don't care about capital letter or not, but linux do. Check it.

Change:

```
<Ecophone_Specialoffer_Model_Observer>
```

To:

```
<ecophone_specialoffer_model_observer>
```

Comment: The only reason to work on local server and don't on final server it's this one. But it's possible you forget some archive, or forget to active the module, or clean the cache, or you'r using Compiled mode on. Check this.

Comment: Compiler mode is in Disable status, module is in active and cleared cache, but still could not trigger it:(

Comment: you have in mind, you need clear the var/chache after all change on .xml?

Comment: i've pretty sure this is about name and references on xml, but don't know what is exactaly

Comment: Observer.php is not getting called, there could be some problem with config.xml, anyway thanks for replaying:)

Answer (score 0):

put your events code in

```
<global>

<!-- you event here -->

</global>
```

so it is like

```
<global>
<events>
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
               <ecophone_specialoffer_model_observer>
                  <type>singleton</type>
                  <class>Ecophone_Specialoffer_Model_Observer</class>
                  <method>changingPrice</method>
               </ecophone_specialoffer_model_observer>
           </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

This will solve your issue.
regards
Sukhwant

Answer (score 0):

Please Login to magento admin go to system->tools->compilation and click disable.

Now it will work in server.